# MySQL TEXT field performance

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have several TEXT and/or MEDIUMTEXT fields in each of our 1000 MySQL tables.  I now know that TEXT fields are written to disk rather than in memory when queried.  Is that also true even if that field is not called in the query?  For example, if I have a table (tbExam) with 2 fields (id int(11) and comment text) and I run SELECT id FROM tbExam, does MySQL still have to write that to disk before returning results or will it run that query in memory?

I am trying to figure out if I need to reconfigure our actual db tables to switch to varchar(xxxx) or keep the text fields and reconfigure the queries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> I now know that TEXT fields are written to disk rather than in memory when queried

`TEXT` fields are written to disk only when the query requires a temporary table to store intermediate results of multiple sort or aggregate operations. This, for instance, happens when you mix `DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` on different columns within a single query.

If your `TEXT` column is not a part of this temporary table, `MySQL` will first try to create it using `MEMORY` engine (which does not support `TEXT`).

`MyISAM` engine for a temporary table will only be chosen if the size of this table will exceed `@@tmp_table_size` or there are some columns `MEMORY` does not support.

For a query like this:

```
SELECT  id
FROM    tbExam
```

, a temporary table will not be needed at all.

There is a slight difference in how `InnoDB` storage engine plugin (which is responsible for interaction between `InnoDB` and `MySQL`) behaves with respect to `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` fields: a `VARCHAR` field is passed to the recordset buffer by value while a `TEXT` field is passed by reference.

Internally, `InnoDB` stores `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` fields in a same way: in-row if the whole column fits into half of a page, out-of-row if not. The difference above only concerns `InnoDB / MySQL` interaction issues.

If you don't query for these fields, then there is no difference at all.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I will give you a point of it as soon as I get to 15 reputation points and am allowed to.